# Integration test in spring boot cant found the path of sql file

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

I am writing a integration test for rest api entry.The api require to initialize database before the test.However it gives an error which showing it cant find any path to my sql file.

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = { SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.class })

class OrderServiceApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;



    //@Sql("INSERT INTO user_info(name) VALUES \"alex\" ")
    @Test
    @Sql("{/resources/schema.sql}")
    void shouldCreatePost() throws Exception {
        JobOrder job=jobRepository.save(createjob());
        String request=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(job);


        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/Job/Joborder")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(request))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());


    }



    JobOrder createjob(){
        JobOrder job=new JobOrder();
        job.setTitle("Hiring software engineer");
        job.setDescription("responsible for developing and maintaining mobile app");
        job.setRequirement("Need to know basic sql springboot,2 years exp");
        job.setSalary(234);
        job.setOrder_id(1);
        return job;

    }
}
```

schema.sql:

```sql
INSERT INTO user_info (name) VALUES ('India');
```

and i got an error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [com/example/OrderService/{/resources/schema.sql}]

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:239)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.execute(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:269)
    at org.springframewo
```

My properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

My Path:
[image]

I don't know what is the problem on my path. And I am wondering if there are problem on my test script or strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Several things are wrong with your `@Sql("{/resources/schema.sql}")`.

1. the `{` and `}` do not belong into the path, why did you add it in the first place?
2. You don't need to include the `/resources` directory in the path. To find out what the path of your file is, open the `target/test-classes` and have a look. Everything that resides in the `resources` directory will be placed in the root directory. If your file was in `resources/sql/test.sql` it would be available under `sql/test.sql`.

#### Solution

```java
@Sql("schema.sql")
```